# Hashtable bucket implementation

Tags: c++, list, vector, hashmap, hashtable

In every hash table implementation I have seen, a hash is used to pick a "bucket" which is a list of items and then iterate over that list until we find the item we want.

My question is why is it always a list? From what I hear, a vector is almost always more efficient, so why not use a vector as the bucket? Is there some property of lists that makes them ideal for use as a bucket in a hash table?

I'm using the C++ terminology for vector here, but it really applies in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash tables are used in places where speed is a concern.

Appending or removing elements from a `std::vector` is much slower compared to `std::list` which is implemented as doubly-linked list.

When adding an element to `std::vector` all elements have to be moved in memory if the vector size exceeds the vector capacity. In `std::list` only the memory for the new element is allocated and the next-pointer of the last element has to be adjusted.

When removing an element from `std::vector` all subsequent elements have to be moved in memory. In `std::list` only the prev and next pointers have to be adjusted.

**Maybe another reason**: If using std::list the elements would never be moved in memory and you can use naked pointers to address the elements once they are added to the map. When using std::vector the elements are moved if the vector is resized and all naked pointers would be left dangling

OOT: Another solution would be to not use a list for the bucket at all: If the new element would hash to position 7 and this position is already taken, the new element would be written to position 8 (an so on). This solution is very fast if the hashtable is nearly empty and slow if the table is nearly full. If the number of elements exceed the hash table size it has to be resized and reorganized which is a very costly operation.

Comment: Appending to a vector is ammortized O (1), so inserting to the hashtable should be also. Removing, on I agree, but retrieving elements would be much faster as iteration over a vector is significantly faster. I still don't understand why a list is always chosen. What if you do a lot of appends and gets, but not many removes? Seems like vector is faster there...

Comment: The complexity of appending an element to a vector is O(1) but it is still a very expensive operation of the size exceeds the capacity.

Comment: So it's not for for realtime applications, but for high throughput, ammortized is all you care about

Comment: Maybe there is another reason: If using std::list the elements would never be moved in memory and you can use naked pointers to address the elements. When using std::vector the elements are moved if the vector is resized and all naked pointers would be left dangling.

Comment: Ooh, true, didn't think about that... add it to your answer, I'll upvote

Comment: Maybe another reason: an empty std::vector consumes 12 bytes of storage while an empty std::list only consumes 8. Take a look at this list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438470.aspx